# Error using Polybase to load Parquet file: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class parquet.io.api.Binary

Tags: parquet, external-tables, polybase, azure-data-studio

I have a snappy.parquet file with a schema like this:

```
{
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "MyTinyInt",
            "type": "byte",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}

        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Update: parquet-tools reveals this:

```
############ Column(MyTinyInt) ############
name: MyTinyInt
path: MyTinyInt
max_definition_level: 1
max_repetition_level: 0
physical_type: INT32
logical_type: Int(bitWidth=8, isSigned=true)
converted_type (legacy): INT_8
```

When I try and run a stored procedure in Azure Data Studio to load this into an external staging table with PolyBase I get the error:

```
11:16:21Started executing query at Line 113
Msg 106000, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class parquet.io.api.Binary (java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; parquet.io.api.Binary is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

The load into the external table works fine with only varchars

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [domain].[TempTable] 
    (
        ...
        MyTinyInt tinyint NULL,
        ...
        
    )
    WITH
    (
        LOCATION = ''' + @Location + ''',
        DATA_SOURCE = datalake,
        FILE_FORMAT = parquet_snappy
    )
```

The data will eventually be merged into a Data Warehouse Synapse table. In that table the column will have to be of type tinyint.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and good support plan in Azure, so I've got an answer from Microsoft:

> there is a known bug in ADF for this particular scenario: The **date**
> type in parquet should be mapped as data type date in Sql sever
> however, ADF incorrectly converts this type to Datetime2 which causes
> a conflict in PolyBase. I have confirmation for the core engineering
> team that this will be rectified with a fix by the end of November and
> will be published directly into the ADF product.
>
> In the meantime, as a workaround:
>
> 1. Create the target table with data type **DATE** as opposed to **DATETIME2**
> 2. Configure the Copy Activity Sink settings to use **Copy Command** as opposed to PolyBase

but even **Copy command** don't work for me, so only one workaround is to use **Bulk insert**, but Bulk is extremely slow and on big datasets it's would be a problem